# Sort List Of Objects By Properties C# (Custom Sort Order)

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, sorting

I currently have a list of objects that I am trying sort for a custom made grid view. I am hoping that I can achieve it without creating several customized algorithms. Currently I have a method called on page load that sorts the list by customer name, then status. I have a customized status order (new, in progress, has issues, completed, archived) and no matter which sort is used (customer, dates, so on) it should sort the status in the correct order. For example:

I have two customers with two orders each, the first customer is Betty White, the second is Mickey Mouse. Currently, Betty has a new order, and a completed order and Mickey has an order in progress and another on that has issues. So the display order should be:

> Betty, New :: Betty, Completed
>
> Mickey, In Progress :: Mickey, Has Issues

I am currently using `Packages.OrderBy(o => o.Customer).ThenBy(o => o.Status)`. This works effectively to get the customers sorted, however this doesn't eliminate the custom sorting of the status property.

What would be the most efficient and standards acceptable method to achieve this result?

```
case PackageSortType.Customer:
     Packages = Packages.OrderBy(o => o.Customer).ThenBy(o=>o.Status).ToList<Package>();
break;
```

I previously created a method that sorted by status only, however it is my belief that throwing the OrderBy into that algorithm would just jumble the status back up in the end.

```
private void SortByStatus() {
    // Default sort order is: New, In Progress, Has Issues, Completed, Archived
    List<Package> tempPackages = new List<Package>();
    string[] statusNames = new string[5] { "new", "inProgress", "hasIssue", "completed", "archived" };
    string currentStatus = string.Empty;

    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        currentStatus = statusNames[x];

        for (int y = 0; y < Packages.Count; y++) {
            if (tempPackages.Contains(Packages[y])) continue;
            else {
                if (Packages[y].Status == currentStatus)
                    tempPackages.Add(Packages[y]);
            }
        }
    }
    Packages.Clear();
    Packages = tempPackages;
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if it is relevant or not; however, the Packages list is stored in Session.

**EDIT**

---

Thanks to Alex Paven I have resolved the issue of custom sorting my status. I ended up creating a new class for the status and making it derive from IComparable, then created a CompareTo method that forced the proper sorting of the status.

For those who are curious about the solution I came up with (it still needs to be cleaned up), it's located below:

```
public class PackageStatus : IComparable<PackageStatus> {
public string Value { get; set; }
int id = 0;
static string[] statusNames = new string[5] { "new", "inProgress", "hasIssue", "completed", "archived" };

public int CompareTo(PackageStatus b) {
    if (b != null) {
        if (this == b) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (this.Value == statusNames[i]) { id = i; }
            if (b.Value == statusNames[i]) { b.id = i; }
        }
    }

    return Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(id, b.id);
}
}
```

Use:

```
Packages.OrderBy(o => o.Customer).ThenBy(o => o.Status).ToList<Package>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking; why can't you use the Linq expressions in your first code sample? There's OrderByDescending in addition to OrderBy, so you can mix and match the sort order as you desire.

Comment: I didn't notice the OrderByDescending in the intellisense so thank you for point that out; however the biggest issue is the sort by status; I'm not sure if I can put the OrderBy into my status sort method without messing it up, is there a way to customize the OrderBy? Because no matter which direction it is ordered in the status order should remain the same.

Comment: But that was my point, why make the sort so complicated when you can do it with Linq?

Comment: I can look into that, I greatly appreciate the input!

Comment: Oh, you have your status as a string which is not inherently sortable in the order you'd want. Well if you can't change it to an enum for instance, or don't want to keep another field around for sorting, you can use an IComparer which sorts the statuses like you want and then OderBy(p => p.Status, myStatusComparer)

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, I can shift the status into an enum; it wouldn't be an issue. I could still use Linq to sort it at that point correct?

Comment: Sure. If you just want to test out quick things like this might I suggest https://dotnetfiddle.net/ like so: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vY0V8I

Comment: Or https://dotnetfiddle.net/i532u7 with a custom comparer just for fun (it's horribly written and only reverses the order of names and but you get the idea)